# Parameterization of xpath value

Tags: xpath

The below statement is working perfectly alright where I am choosing a calender value.
 `calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay')][input[contains(@value, '**Aug 01**')]]/span")).click();`

However, I tried to parameterise the date by replacing value by a variable. but , It dint work.

date = Aug 01

`calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay')][input[contains(@value, **date**)]]/span")).click();`

can you guide me here ?

Comment: which language you are using with `selenium` ?

Comment: Yes, I am using selenium

Comment: Yes, I am using selenium tool and using Java as coding language

Comment: Another non-answer: Your assertion would be brittle if you change the "glitz" in your HTML. Instead, give the actual target span a unique ID (such as calendar_309, where 309 is your nearest relevant record ID). Then use string-concatenation to shove the 309 directly into your span: By.xpath("//span[ @id = 'calendar_" + id + "' ]). That makes for ugly code but a non-brittle test. And your actual question - how to insert a parameter into By.xpath() - still needs a good answer. "All" XPath systems support parameterization, so By.xpath() should.

Comment: Hi Phlip,thanks for your suggestion.However, the tree structure do not have id <div class="MeCalendarMonthDay MeCalendarWeekDay3" style="width:14.285714285714286%;height:50px">
<span>14</span>
<input type="hidden" value="Wed Aug 14 2013">
</div>

Answer (score 0):

`calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay')][input[contains(@value, '**" + date + "**')]]/span")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set date variable as String:

```
calender.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'MeCalendarMonthDay')][input[contains(@value, '**" + date + "**')]]/span")).click();
```